# Google BigQuery Standard SQL - Sales Sliding Window

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wondering how best to do both a tumbling and sliding window in BigQuery ***standardSQL*** (not legacy).

Apache Spark makes this pretty easy - for a 'sliding' window of length 10 mins sliding every 5 mins, groupBy(window("10 minutes","5 minutes)) and for a tumbling window groupBy(window("10 minutes")).

Consider I have a simplified order row with:

```
orderId, 
orderPlacedTimestamp, 
orderTotals.grandTotalNet, 
orderTotals.grandTotalGross
```

(note the struct on the totals)

and I need two total aggregate order sales value as:

1. tumbling HOURLY window of sales
2. sliding 10 MINUTE / 5 MINUTE window (as described above).

I started this in using a SQL `over` but got a bit messy with partitioning, timestamps and getting the right start and end windows.  For each the result set should be:

```
windowStartTime, 
windowEndTime, 
windowTotalAmount
```

So the windows have a starting and ending time (which is crucial for sliding given the length of the window 10 is different to the sliding duration 5 so a given row can be in multiple windows as a result).

How do I do this in BigQuery?

UPDATE 11/06 WITH CURRENT SQL:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(FIRST_VALUE(ts_5min*5*60) OVER(w)) as startWindowTime,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(LAST_VALUE(ts_5min*5*60) OVER(w)) as endWindowTime,
  SUM(orderTotalNetConverted) OVER(ORDER BY ts_5min RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as windowSalesTotal
FROM (
  SELECT 
    CAST(UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(orderPlacedTimestamp, MINUTE))/60/5 AS INT64)
      AS ts_5min,
    orderTotalNetConverted
  FROM orders
)
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts_5min RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
ORDER BY startWindowTime desc
```

Comment: please edit and add the SQL you've written so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumbling window is easier to do, it is just a regular `GROUP BY` at hourly intervals:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(orderPlacedTimestamp, HOUR), 
  SUM(orderTotals.grandTotalNet)
FROM T
GROUP BY 1
```

For sliding window, I would first normalize timestamps to 5 minute intervals using following:

1. `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(orderPlacedTimestamp, MINUTE)` to get to minute boundary
2. `UNIX_SECONDS` to convert to seconds since epoch
3. Divide by 60 to get minutes
4. Divide by 5 to get 5 minute interval
5. Round to integer:

`CAST(UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(orderPlacedTimestamp, MINUTE))/60/5 AS INT64)`

Now you can use standard `OVER()` clause to get 10 minute window, which means 2 such intervals at a time, and in order to get start time, use `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function:

```
SELECT
  orderId,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(FIRST_VALUE(ts_5min*5*60) OVER(w)) startWindowTime,
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(FIRST_VALUE(ts_5min*5*60) OVER(w)),
                INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) endWindowTime,
  SUM(grandTotalNet) OVER(w)
FROM (
  SELECT 
  *,
  CAST(UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(orderPlacedTimestamp, MINUTE))/60/5 AS INT64) 
    AS ts_5min
  FROM t
)
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts_5min RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: thanks mosha Ill give it a try!  So how do I get the 'startWindowTime' and 'endWindowTime' for each row in the sliding windows?  e.g start = 2017-06-06 14:00:00....end = 2017-06-06 14:10:00 for each row?

Comment: Thanks heaps Mosha - couple of things.  1. I tried to add the end window time as well as: TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(LAST_VALUE(ts_5min*5*60) OVER(w)) as endWindowTime, using the 'lastvalue', but the end window enedup being the same?  What am I doing wrong with this?  2. I dont seem to seen any of the :05 slides....e.g first window 12:00-12:10, second shold be 12:05-12:15 (slide by 5, still length of 10).....did your own local test produce the :05 starting times?  Ill update my origial post with my code....thanks a million!

Comment: Wonder if this could be made more simpler for users by making a UDF?  Have you any experience with this? Maybe something for me to look at once weve nutted the core SQL.  Compared to say spark this is a bit more complex and much harder to read, even if it does work (which of course is the main thing :)....cherers mate!

Comment: Oh I retract the second comment my appologies there were some windows starting with :05 sorry!  Were just quite a few pages in the result set over :)

Comment: I updated answer to add endWindowTime (it is just 10 minutes after start time). I don't believe UDFs can be used here, since they don't work on group of rows. TVF could've worked, but BigQuery doesn't yet support them. I agree, SQL is harder to read for this problem than Spark

Answer (score 1):

Below is for `sliding 10 MINUTE / 5 MINUTE window`

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH starts AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(first, HOUR), INTERVAL step MINUTE) AS start
  FROM 
    (SELECT MIN(orderPlacedTimestamp) AS first, MAX(orderPlacedTimestamp) AS last FROM YourTable), 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(last, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(first, HOUR), MINUTE) , 5)) AS step
)
SELECT 
  start, 
  SUM(orderTotals.grandTotalNet) AS net, 
  SUM(orderTotals.grandTotalGross) AS gross
FROM starts AS s JOIN YourTable AS t
ON t.orderPlacedTimestamp BETWEEN s.start AND TIMESTAMP_ADD(start, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
GROUP BY start
ORDER BY start
```

As Mosha mentioned in his answer - tumbling HOURLY window is easy - but if you will need different window side - above approach is more flexible (I think) and easy to adjust for any window size, type by changing respective `5` and `10` in query code
But overall - wanted to mention  - using analytic function is more optimal than joining

Comment: thanks Mikhail!  This is another good option - is the performance enough of a difference to warrant sticking to using an analytic function - our datasets arent huge.  Thanks heaps for taking the time!

Comment: really depends - there cons and pros on both sides - and I think depends on specific case. the main criteria of course  - whatever option you have - it at least must work as expected - if both work - test performance and make a decision :o)

Comment: Mikhail, as a bit of a guru, can you give me a hand with some timestamp management - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603021/bigquery-string-to-timestamp-retaining-timezone-in-source...thanks!