# BigQuery String to Timestamp retaining Timezone in Source

Tags: google-bigquery

I've looked at other similar posts and not sure they susinctly answer this - maybe they do, sorry if I have missed any points that could answer this.

I have a string

```
"2017-06-16T10:34:57.705+01:00"
```

How do I convert this to a 'Timestamp' Type from the String, but retaining precision (the milliseconds) and the timezone offset?

```
TIMESTAMP("2017-06-16T10:34:57.705+01:00")
```

converts to a Timestamp in UTC and looses the milliseconds precision, I want a timestamp type but retaining all the precison of the local date with the timezone?

```
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez",PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", "2017-06-16T10:34:57.705+01:00"),"Europe/London")
```

This retains the precison and has the offset but is a String - then I lose this trying to convert to a timestamp again TIMESTAMP(x)!

I feel Im going around in circles any help appreciated thanks!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The [`TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type) type is some point in time relative to the UNIX epoch. It has microsecond precision and does not encode a timezone, though the `TIMESTAMP`-related functions use UTC by default, e.g. for extracting a `DATE`.

It's not clear why you want to retain the original timezone of the timestamps, but one thing you could do would be to keep an integer column with the offset from UTC, which you can compute using `TIMESTAMP_DIFF` between the input timestamp ignoring Its timezone in the string and the input timestamp using its timezone in the string.

For the precision, you can check for equality between the provided timestamp and the result of `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC` with e.g. `MILLISECOND` to see what the precision is. I don't know what you want to do with the information, but you could use a string or integer to represent the precision as well.

Comment: Thanks Elliot - the reason for keeping the timezone is that time based queires (e.g tumbling window) are using (displaying at least to the users in the region) the loacl time on the graph, not UTC.  We have offices world wide and want to show the relevant time (e.g of orders placed) including retaining things like daylight savings / summer times.  I do stored the original as a string anyway as it comes in JSON.  Appreciate the comments thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Just as a complement, you are not actually losing precision when you apply the `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` as you can check by using the `UNIX_MILLIS` function:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT "2017-06-16T10:34:57.705+01:00" as date union all
  SELECT "2017-06-16T10:34:57.999+01:00" as date
)

SELECT
  date,
  UNIX_MILLIS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", date, "Europe/London")) millis_date
FROM data
```

Results in:

```
Row date                            millis_date  
1   2017-06-16T10:34:57.999+01:00   1497605697999    
2   2017-06-16T10:34:57.705+01:00   1497605697705
```